# Bug in Next JS 13: Unable to Run Server-Side Page Loader in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, loader, next.js13

I am experiencing an issue in Next.js 13 where I am unable to run a loader for a server-side page. Before upgrading to version 13, I had a custom loader that executed on the server side when rendering certain pages, but after the update, the loader no longer seems to work as expected. The loader is essential for pre-fetching data and enhancing the server-side rendering performance.

I have tried reconfiguring the loader and ensured that all necessary dependencies are updated, but the issue persists. It seems that Next.js 13 might have introduced some changes that affect the behavior of server-side page loaders.

The purpose of this loader was to pre-fetch and process data on the server side before rendering the page, aiming to enhance the server-side rendering performance and improve the user experience.

Before the upgrade, this custom loader was working flawlessly in previous versions of Next.js. However, after migrating to version 13, I noticed that the loader is no longer functioning as expected. When navigating to the respective page that should trigger the loader, it does not execute on the server side, and as a result, the page is rendered without the pre-fetched data.

I have made efforts to reconfigure the loader implementation and ensure that all necessary dependencies are updated to be compatible with Next.js 13. Despite my attempts, the issue persists, leading me to believe that there might be some changes or incompatibilities introduced in Next.js 13 that are affecting the behavior of server-side page loaders.

I have a page called `page.jsx` inside the `app` directory. It contains the following code:

```
import store from './store/store.js';

export default function ServerComponent() {
  let reduxValue = store.getState().siteState;

  return <div>Server Component</div>;
}
```

Additionally, there's a client component called `ClientComponent`, which includes a button. When this button is clicked, I want to change the Redux value and access it in the server-side `page.jsx` file.

```
'use client';
import { changeSiteState } from "../store/siteStateSlice";
import { useAppDispatch } from "react-redux";

export default function ClientComponent() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const handleChange = () => {
    dispatch(changeSiteState('Button Clicked'));
  }

  return <button onClick={() => { handleChange() }}>Client Component</button>;
}
```

However, when I click on the button and navigate to the server-side `page.jsx`, the new value is not being updated to "Button Clicked." It seems that the change in the Redux variable from the client side is not synchronized with the server. I suspect this might be an issue with Next.js version 13, which could be preventing the synchronization of the Redux global value from the client to the server. I would like to know how to resolve this issue. Please avoid providing solutions at this moment.

Comment: Have you looked at the app router in version 13? I think it might solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, actually my route is not changing

Comment: I don't understand how you get a a page load without navigating. How is that happening?

Comment: onClick event, I update cookies, and these updated cookies are then passed within the same page to obtain refreshed data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have a page called `page.jsx` inside the `app` directory. It contains the following code:

```jsx
import store from './store/store.js';

export default function ServerComponent() {
  let reduxValue = store.getState().siteState;

  return <div>Server Component</div>;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, there's a client component called `ClientComponent`, which includes a button. When this button is clicked, I want to change the Redux value and access it in the server-side `page.jsx` file.

```jsx
'use client';
import { changeSiteState } from "../store/siteStateSlice";
import { useAppDispatch } from "react-redux";

export default function ClientComponent() {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const handleChange = () => {
    dispatch(changeSiteState('Button Clicked'));
  }

  return <button onClick={() => { handleChange() }}>Client Component</button>;
}
```

Comment: However, when I click on the button and navigate to the server-side `page.jsx`, the new value is not being updated to "Button Clicked." It seems that the change in the Redux variable from the client side is not synchronized with the server. I suspect this might be an issue with Next.js version 13, which could be preventing the synchronization of the Redux global value from the client to the server. I would like to know how to resolve this issue. Please avoid providing solutions at this moment.

Comment: I resolved the problem by incorporating 'loader.jsx' as a client component within 'Page.jsx', which is the default server component. I included 'use client' at the top of 'loader.jsx', effectively addressing the issue.